# Is this figure of a man a statue or a monument?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, word-difference

[image]My friend and I were arranging a place to meet. 
She suggested the place and referred this as a monument. 
I thought this is a statue.
What is a common word to call this, statue or monument?
I just know that the Statue of Liberty is called *statue*.

Comment: It's a **statue** for sure.I woudn't refer to it as **monument**.

Comment: @SovereignSun: **Monument** need not refer to the place or thing only in terms of its physicality; the word can refer to the *purpose* served by the thing, *The statue is a monument to the person depicted.*

Answer (score 13):

Actually, in this case, it is possible to call it a statue or a monument.

> - [statue](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/statue)
>     a large art object, often representing a person or an animal, that is made from a hard material, esp. stone or metal
> - [monument](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/monument)
>     an object, esp. large and made of stone, built to remember and show respect for a person or group of people, or a special place made for this purpose:
>     *While in Washington, D.C., we visited a number of historical monuments.*
>     *fig. The annual arts festival is a monument to (= is a result of) her vision and hard work.*
>
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

Notice that the object in the picture is definitely a large object representing a person, and it is also (presumably) there to honor that person.

I would call it a statue though because statues are more closely associated with the likeness of the person, whereas monuments are often buildings or other large structures.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't by default any statue a monument?

Comment: @LucianSava, no.  A statue can just be art.  A monument is built specifically to remember or honor someone or something.

Comment: Oops! I missed that, @fixer1234!:)

Comment: @Lucian Sava: And a monument need not be a statue, as for instance the Washington Monument.